# How can I convert mixed minute-and-second duration values in a log (with logfmt format) to a consistent unit?

Tags: logs

I have a log file in logfmt, with lines like these

```
duration=38.924266437s job=267842 project=507
duration=38.924266437s job=267842 project=507
duration=2m56.408984141s job=267850 project=745
duration=2m56.408984141s job=267850 project=745
duration=3m38.211342699s job=267846 project=173
duration=3m38.211342699s job=267846 project=173
duration=3m38.690043053s job=267843 project=173
duration=3m38.690043053s job=267843 project=173
...
```

How can convert the duration values to one type of unit of measure (seconds or minutes)?

Comment: You want to generate a new file as the result, or do something else with it?

Comment: Is it just minutes and seconds, or can there be larger units too? Do you want the fractional seconds carried through?

Comment: Is there anything else on each line or just the two fields `job` and `duration`?

Comment: @roaima until now, I only have minutes and seconds. the log has other fields but I have removed it with `grep -Po`.

Comment: @spuck I would like to do a basic analysis of the duration (average, percentile, etc) or maybe with some tools like asciigraph. I was trying to avoid to move the data to another computer and create scripts to analyze it.

Comment: Can you please put dummy data back in where the other fields would go. Otherwise you'll likely get someone assuming they can bind a pattern match for the duration to end-of-line. Unless you really want a solution that might only work with these two fields per line.

Comment: Do you want the fractional seconds carried through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'[= ]' '{ 
  n=split($2, a, "m")
  sub($2, sprintf("%.9f", (n==1 ? a[1] : 60*a[1]+a[2])))
}1' file
```

Output:

```
duration=38.924266437 job=267842 project=507
duration=38.924266437 job=267842 project=507
duration=176.408984141 job=267850 project=745
duration=176.408984141 job=267850 project=745
duration=218.211342699 job=267846 project=173
duration=218.211342699 job=267846 project=173
duration=218.690043053 job=267843 project=173
duration=218.690043053 job=267843 project=173
```

- Use `=` and   as field separators, the second field `$2` contains the target string, e.g. `38.924266437s`.
- Split the second field on string `m` into array `a`, `n` is the length of the array.
- Calculate the new value: If `n` is `1`, then use the first array value (the seconds), otherwise calculate the seconds from both array values.
- Replace the second field with the calculated value formatted as float.
- Print the record.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

regex_min='duration=([0-9]+)m'
regex_sec='([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)s'

while read -r line; do
	[[ $line =~ $regex_sec ]]
	sec=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
	frac=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
	if [[ $line =~ $regex_min ]]; then
		sec=$(( sec + 60*${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ))
	fi

	echo $line: $sec.$frac
done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZBPT4MwGIfP9FO8RhLAZay0pYALh2lMdvGi3pAs/OmkywADGE2MfnUsmcMl87Td@vZ9@vx@aZq0Rd9fXsxSWc1SNSDUiBfxsSplFRr5W5N0sq5CM8LTIJ5YpfG7bkUWGvvbZ3t/ag2E3gu5FdCIJIdpA1tZiTnkNdKiCPRhgvAb9NECcYy0waZ/3iwel6uHu/vF0@0ycuIvpK2b5GhBhoVcwz861Vnp5tAVokLazmqaMKRMgOOr4wiwLJUiEdJEVtQ74TXo6oWtD@EoryvR9@M/UN8OCCOcM@q1sKnTkHDPZwRem3ojsi50sYdOpEnpcpthP/CZw5w/3sUj7zH3dJ6Wqg9xHKoaBcFBHz7yjkfP5HmAMaPYpQc8PYf/AQ)

Save it as `process.sh` and then run:
`cat myfile | bash process.sh`

Here's the output you would get with your sample data:

```bash
duration=38.924266437s job=267842 project=507: 38.924266437
duration=38.924266437s job=267842 project=507: 38.924266437
duration=2m56.408984141s job=267850 project=745: 176.408984141
duration=2m56.408984141s job=267850 project=745: 176.408984141
duration=3m38.211342699s job=267846 project=173: 218.211342699
duration=3m38.211342699s job=267846 project=173: 218.211342699
duration=3m38.690043053s job=267843 project=173: 218.690043053
```